# Vim how to restore file from renaming?

Tags: vim

I have deleted some content in a file from vim, which is not in any VCS, and without noticing that I am changing the wrong place, I renamed the file use `Nerdtree`, and saved the file for a lot of times, so there is no swap file (`.swp`), how can I restore the file to the original state use `vim`?

Cannot use undo, because the renaming I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found my changes in registers by `:registers`, because I used `dd` to delete the content, so I was able to use `"[registerName]p` to get it back, so my problem is solved